# Multi-thread use fstream to read different files but caused segment fault

Tags: c++, file-io

First I use a python script to generate 600 files eg:one0 ...one199 two0...two199 five0...five199
Then I write a C++ program which is used fstream to read different files.
My code:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    init();//init the data structure
    int createthread=0;

    signal(SIGINT,CtrlHandlerRoutine);

    pthread_t *workthread= new pthread_t[6];
    ThreadParam *param=new ThreadParam[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {   
        param[i].thread_index=i;
    }   

    for (int index = 0; index < 2; ++index)
    {   
    /* code */
      if(pthread_create(&workthread[index],NULL,WorkerThreadFunction,&param[index])==0)
      {   
        createthread++;
        fflush(stdout);
       }   
    }   

    while(!gExitFlag)
    {   
       usleep(100000);
    }   

    gWorkThreadStopFlag=true;

    while(gStoppedThread<createthread)
    {   
      usleep(1);
    }   

    delete[] workthread;
    for(int i=0; i<DELAY_TYPE_NUM; i++)
    {   
       printProcDelayResult(gProcDelay[i]);
    }   
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Thread func:

```
void* WorkerThreadFunction(void* arg)
{
    ThreadParam *param=(ThreadParam*) arg;
int threadnum=param->thread_index;

int max_index,min_index;
int protype=0;
string filetype="";

//memset(&sessionProcDelay,0,21*sizeof(sessionProcDelay)); init the data structure
//fstream fd;//define a handle of the file
switch(threadnum)
{
    case 0:
        max_index=99;
        min_index=0;
        protype=1;
        filetype="one";
        break;
    case 1:
        max_index=199;
        min_index=100;
        protype=1;
        filetype="one";
        break;
    case 2:
        max_index=99;
        min_index=0;
        protype=2;
        filetype="two";
        break;
    case 3:
        max_index=199;
        min_index=100;
        protype=2;
        filetype="two";
        break;
    case 4:
        max_index=99;
        min_index=0;
        protype=3;
        filetype="five";
        break;
    case 5:
        max_index=199;
        min_index=100;
        protype=3;
        filetype="five";
        break;
}
for (int i = min_index; i <=max_index; ++i)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss<<i;
    string filename=filetype+oss.str();
    fstream fd(filename.c_str(),ios::in);
    if(!fd.is_open())
    {
        printf("Can not open the file\n");
    }
    int num=0;
    char text[6];
    while(!fd.eof())
    {
        num++;
        fd.getline(text,6);
        string line(text);
        int mvalue=atoi(line.c_str());
        f_StatProcessDelay(sessionProcDelay[i*DELAY_TYPE_NUM],protype,mvalue);
        /*if(mvalue==0)
        {
            printf("filename:%s,line:%d content %s\n",filename.c_str(),num,line.c_str());
        }*/
    }
    fd.close();

}
printf("OVER\n");

while(!gWorkThreadStopFlag)
{
    usleep(1000);
}
pthread_mutex_lock(&gDataLock);
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < DELAY_TYPE_NUM; ++k)
    {
        /* code */
        if(sessionProcDelay[j*DELAY_TYPE_NUM+k].procDelayMax>0) // if process delay data is available, if not procDelayMax is -1
        {
            int procTypeIndex = sessionProcDelay[j*DELAY_TYPE_NUM+k].procDelayType;
            updateTotalProcDelay(sessionProcDelay[j*DELAY_TYPE_NUM+k], gProcDelay[procTypeIndex-1]);
        }
    }
}
gStoppedThread++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&gDataLock);

}
```

And GDB log:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7935d1d in std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>   >::getline(char*, long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000401db6 in WorkerThreadFunction (arg=0x604054) at mutithreadcal.cpp:147
#2  0x00007ffff7bc85f0 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff71bf84d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What's the root cause for this segement fault?

Comment: getline should be safe on distinct objects. You could try valgrind to get more information about error.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but unless the files are on separate hard drives, chances are you want to do this single-threaded anyway. Multiple threads reading from one disk drive usually slows things down by forcing the disk drive to do extra seeking.

Comment: I found the root cause for the segment fault but why the gdb's bt stay at the getline function.